# Añadir elemento al final del menu en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

¡Hola!, tengo este código para añadir un boton de login y logout en un menú de wordpress y funciona perfectamente, el problema es que me lo añade al principio del menú y necesito añadirlo al final, ¿alguna idea? 
**!Muchas gracias de antemano!**

```
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args)
{
  if(is_user_logged_in())
  {
    $newitems = '<li class="important-item"><a  title="Logout" href="'. wp_logout_url('index.php') .'"><span>'.__('Logout','divi').'</span></a></li>';
    $newitems .= $items;
  }
  else
  {
    $newitems = '<li class="important-item"><a title="Login" href="http://localhost:8888/webmenu/mi-cuenta"><span>'.__('Login', 'divi').'</span></a></li>';
    $newitems .= $items;
  }
  return $newitems;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo ahí es tomar los elementos existentes del menú que están en el parámetro `$items` de la función y añadirle un nuevo elemento de acuerdo a que el usuario esté o no logueado. Entendido eso, tu código tiene dos problemas.

El primero es que esta asignación se hace al revés:

```
$newitems .= $items;
```

Lo que estás haciendo ahí es añadir el botón y **a continuación** poner los ítems que estaban en el menú, por eso el botón aparece al principio. Tenés que cambiarlo por esto, tanto dentro del `if` como del `else`:

```
$items .= $newitems;
```

El segundo error está en el `return` de la función. La lógica de esto es que tomamos los elementos del menú que están en `$items`, le añadimos un botón y devolvemos esa misma variable con las modificaciones que hicimos. Cambiá `return $newitems;` por:

```
return $items;
```

Ojalá te sirva y me haya explicado lo suficientemente bien.

Comment: Hola Lagg3r, lo primero muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de responder, y lo segundo muchas gracias por la ayuda porque ha funcionado perfectamente, además comprendo la explicación que has dado. ¡Un saludo y muchas gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 0):

Dejo por aquí el código corregido gracias a la ayuda de Lagg3r por si le sirve a alguien.

````
{
  if(is_user_logged_in())
  {
    $newitems = '<li class="important-item"><a  title="Logout" href="'. wp_logout_url('index.php') .'"><span>'.__('Logout','divi').'</span></a></li>';
    $items .= $newitems;
  }
  else
  {
    $newitems = '<li class="important-item"><a title="Login" href="http://localhost:8888/webmenu/mi-cuenta"><span>'.__('Login', 'divi').'</span></a></li>';
    $items .= $newitems;
  }
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2); ```
````